# FrameLayout with the TextView on the bottom

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got a FrameLayout like this. It contains two overlaying images:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_frame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/image_areas"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/image_mask"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/walker"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

I want to add a `TextView` below this `FrameLayout`. Is it possible or does `FrameLayout` take all the space on the screen? Can I put my FrameLayout and TextView in a sort of  `LinearLayout`?

**Edit:** The problem is that my `TextView` is not displayed when Im putting it in a LinearLayout or RelaiveLayout together with my FrameLayout.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a `RelativeLayout` to hold both your `FrameLayout` and `TextView` and in your `FrameLayout` use the `android:layout_above` atribute. Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/my_frame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/TextViewId" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_areas"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_dialog" />
</FrameLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextViewId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="TextView text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Cant I use the LinearLayout? Is it necessary using RelativeLayout?

Comment: For some reason TextView is not displayed. Any ideas?

Comment: If you want to have the FrameLayout take as much space as possible (e.g. fill parent) except from the TextView's space, i think RelativeLayout is the best solution. It depends on what you need to do.

Comment: Yep, but for some reason TextView is still not displayed :)

Comment: @Dennis Weird, i have tested this code before posting it. Have you set the text the TextView will show?

Comment: Yep, tried using Button instead the TextView - works fine. It should be some sort of my stupid omission. Ill sort it out. Thanks for help Angelo!

Answer (score 2):

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/my_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_areas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_dialog" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextViewId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text="layout_gravity is the key here..."/>
</FrameLayout>
```